# Problem with default shell and home directory

Tags: bash, ssh, login

I have recently been granted access to a machine at work. However, I have been having trouble setting up my development environment. Relevant information about the machine:

```
$ uname -a
Linux blackhawk2 3.2.0-41-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 25 03:27:11 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I use OpenSSH to login into to this machine remotely. The thing I noticed immediately, was that my home directory was not set properly.

```
$ echo $HOME
/
```

Further my shell of preference is Bash, but:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/csh
```

I am aware that the home directory and the default shell is setup in '/etc/passwd'. Inspecting this file I find:

```
glperez:x:1015:1015:glperez,,,:/home/glperez:/bin/bash
```

EDIT:
My home directory definitely exists and '/bin/bash' is working properly. Also, user authentication is handled over an authentication server of some kind.  Unfortunately, this information is not readily available to me at this moment.

The strange thing is that on both occasions that I have tried to fix this problem, the first log in results in the expected behavior. That is, my home directory is correctly set and my shell is Bash. Upon logging in again, the problem shows up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is/was with my UID. For some reason, my UID is not consistent.

It seems like something is going wrong when username is being looked up and I am given a temporary UID.

I am now in contact with a system admin to solve this.

Thanks for all the responses!

Answer (score 0):

Read `man 1 login`, read `/etc/login.defs`.  Also see what you have in `$PATH`, `$LOGNAME`.

I'd make sure that `/home/glperez` really exists, with `ls -ld /home/glperez`. If it does not exist, and `/etc/login.defs` permits, you will be given a directory that login is **sure** exists, `/`.

You can also check that `/bin/bash` exists, is executable, and is included in `/etc/shells`

```
ls  -l /bin/bash;ldd /bin/bash;grep /bin/bash /etc/shells
```

You should ask `blackhawk2`'s sysadm how s/he created the `glperez` account. `useradd` or `adduser`? What parameters? Are you supposed to have an encrypted home directory? Does `blackhawk2` authenticate users locally, or over the network (check `/etc/nsswitch.conf`)? If over the network, what does that server think of you?

Comment: Thanks for the response waltinator. I will answer your questions by editing my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that you have exactly this line:

```
glperez:x:1015:1015:glperez,,,:/home/glperez:/bin/bash
```

in `/etc/passwd` file, then you should check all your [shell initialization files](http://linux.die.net/Bash-Beginners-Guide/sect_03_01.html) like `~/.bashrc`, `~/profile` and so on. Most probably you have something like the following commands in one of those files:

```
ksh              #change the shell to ksh
cd /             #chenge the working directory to /

HOME=/
SHELL=/bin/ksh
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have checked all initialization files and nowhere is my HOME or SHELL changed. As I mentioned in my edit, when I log on for the first time everything is fine (although public key authentication is not working) all subsequent attempts to login result in my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following will run bash similar to the way it gets run when you log in, but outputs the filename and line number of each command it runs. It should help you figure out where it changes the `SHELL` variable.

```
PS4='+ $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:' bash -xlic ''
```